# Concat columns from multiple tables into one row without duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

I need to concatenate two columns from diffrent tables, delimited with ";" into one row without duplicates.

**Table 1:**

```
Name
John;Sue
```

**Table 2:**

```
Name
Mary;John
```

**Desired output**

```
Names
John;Sue;Mary
```

I tried with :

```
select listagg(a.Name, ';') within group (order by a.Name) as Names
from Table1 a
join Table2 b on a.id = b.id;
```

but I get "**ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long**" error.

How to do that properly in Oracle?

Comment: "How to do that properly in Oracle?" The proper way is to not store data in delimited strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple string functions:

```sql
WITH t1_positions (id, name, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         1,
         INSTR(name, ';', 1)
  FROM   table1
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         name,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(name, ';', epos + 1)
  FROM   t1_positions
  WHERE  epos > 0
),
t1_strings (id, item) AS (
  SELECT id,
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(name, spos)
         ELSE SUBSTR(name, spos, epos - spos)
         END
  FROM   t1_positions
),
t2_positions (id, name, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         1,
         INSTR(name, ';', 1)
  FROM   table2
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         name,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(name, ';', epos + 1)
  FROM   t2_positions
  WHERE  epos > 0
),
t2_strings (id, item) AS (
  SELECT id,
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(name, spos)
         ELSE SUBSTR(name, spos, epos - spos)
         END
  FROM   t2_positions
)
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(item, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item) AS name
FROM   (SELECT * FROM t1_strings
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM t2_strings)
GROUP BY id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'John;Sue' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Mary;John' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | John;Mary;Sue |

*Note: you can do it with regular expressions; however, for a large dataset, it is likely to be of an order of magnitude slower.*

---

#### Update

> How to do that properly in Oracle?

Do not store delimited strings and store the data in first normal form (1NF):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'John' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Sue' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Mary' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the query is simply:

```sql
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(name, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS name
FROM   (SELECT * FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM table2)
GROUP BY id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f917ca8930647ed82adf50292b67a8a)*

Comment: @MTO, thanks for answer. This one is a bit easier, but still not a one-liner :).... I didn't imagine that this would be such a problem in SQL these days. Thanks again !

Comment: @Lucy82 Added an update on how to make it simpler; it involves storing the data in 1NF. (And if you want a one-liner then just replace all the carriage returns with spaces in the query... but it'll be a long line.)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming those *are* names and the result doesn't span over more than 4000 characters (which is the `listagg` limit) then one option is to do this (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  table1 (id, name) as
  4    (select 1, 'John;Sue'    from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'Little;Foot' from dual),
  6  table2 (id, name) as
  7    (select 1, 'Mary;John' from dual),
  8  --
  9  union_jack (id, name) as
 10    -- union those two tables
 11    (select id, name from table1
 12     union
 13     select id, name from table2
 14    ),
 15  distname as
 16    -- distinct names
 17    (select distinct
 18            id,
 19            regexp_substr(name, '[^;]+', 1, column_value) name
 20     from union_jack cross join
 21          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 22                              connect by level <= regexp_count(name, ';') + 1
 23                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 24    )
 25  select id,
 26         listagg(d.name, ';') within group (order by d.name) as names
 27  from distname d
 28  group by id;

        ID NAMES
---------- ------------------------------
         1 John;Mary;Sue
         2 Foot;Little

SQL>
```

---

If it really spans over more than 4000 characters, switch to `XMLAGG`; lines #25 onward would be

```
 25  select id,
 26         rtrim(xmlagg (xmlelement (e, d.name || ';') order by d.name).extract
 27                  ('//text()'), ';') as names
 28  from distname d
 29  group by id;

        ID NAMES
---------- ------------------------------
         1 John;Mary;Sue
         2 Foot;Little

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for answers. I think your first answer is the one I need, but one question. Why do I need all this code when both of my tables have set **max. 70 bytes** for columns in question ? How can **listagg** function reach 4000 bytes limit while max. limit of both together can be 140 bytes? Obviously I'm confused about what listagg function does.

Comment: "All this code" because you have to split names (which are delimited by semi-colon) into rows so that you could extract only distinct values per each ID, and **then** aggregate them back. As of exceeding the limit: I wouldn't know, code you posted returns only one table's column value (from table1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a XML-style tecnique before applying `LISTAGG()` in order to provide writing distinct names such as

```sql
WITH t AS
( 
  SELECT RTRIM(DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
                 XMLAGG( 
                        XMLELEMENT(e,name||';')
                       ).EXTRACT('//text()').GETCLOBVAL() ,1),
                ';') AS name  
      FROM ( SELECT t1.name||';'||t2.name AS name
               FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id )
)
 SELECT LISTAGG(REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,'[^;]+',1,level),';') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 0) AS "Names"
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(name,';')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a949948716b34d547c2ff4e3139336ef)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I choosed first answer one as correct one, though they probably all are correct ones. Thanks again !